# using wmctrl to close windows on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Can I close a window using `wmctrl` that is running in wine on Ubuntu?

For context:

```
$ wmctrl -m
Name: compiz
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10.

Also:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x0240a3be -1 mjol N/A
0x02000003  0 mjol Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x0200004c  0 mjol Bottom Expanded Edge Panel
0x01e00024  0 mjol x-nautilus-desktop
0x04800253  0 mjol using wmctrl to close windows - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
0x03c0c8c3  0 mjol Terminal
0x03c53f25  0 mjol Terminal
0x04400001  0 mjol Untitled - SketchUp
0x04400003  0 mjol Instructor
0x04400009  0 mjol SketchUp
```

The window I want to close is the last one:

```
0x04400009  0 mjol SketchUp
```

I've tried the following:

```
$ wmctrl -c "SketchUp"

$ wmctrl -c 0x04400009

$ wmctrl -i 0x04400009

$ wmctrl -c -i 0x04400009
```

But nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you already ask this?  In any case, my bet is Wine doesn't obey the EWMH specs.  `xkill` might work, or might kill the whole Wine session.